# Use the palette material in the theme and apply it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am a beginner in material react. I used a palette in the theme in my code, but it shows me a different color code when it displays. please guide me
theme code

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core";

const primaryColor="#FF4D23";
const Theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTypography: {
          root: {
            fontFamily: "shabnam !important",
            
          }
        },
        palette:{
          primary:{
            main:primaryColor,
            
          }
        }
      }
    });
    
    export default Theme;
```

style code

```
LogoText:{
  
  color:theme.palette.primary.main,
  fontSize:'23px ',
  fontWeight:600,
  marginRight:'10px'
},
```

But it shows
**
color: #3f51b5;
**

Comment: Are you using a top level ThemeProvider (https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#theming) around your components and either makeStyles / withStyles (https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles-withstyles-styled) within your LogoText component?

If so, you might need to pass the theme parameter within your makeStyles / withStyles call:
```const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({ ... })```

Comment: I did, this wrong now?
const useStyles = makeStyles( theme=>({

  
  root: {
    backgroundColor:'white',
    width:'15%',
},
LogoText:{
  
  color:theme.palette.primary.main,
  fontSize:'23px ',
  fontWeight:600,
  marginRight:'10px'
},

Comment: `palette` should not be nested inside `overrides`.

Comment: That's right, thank you